# how to set the counter value to column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have to  insert the table from the value of the column .
My table is

```
row_ID   ID    Code   units    status     
1       AAA    PPP     5        Deny
2       BBB    ZZZ    10        Deny
3       FFF    MMM     7        Deny
4       SSS    YYY    3         Deny
```

Now I have to loop through units values and insert into table as that many times. my first units value is 5 , so for the first record and last record my target table should like 
My table should look like

```
ID    Code       Units      Status
AAA   PPP         1         Deny
AAA   PPP         1         Deny
AAA   PPP         1         Deny
AAA   PPP         1         Deny
AAA   PPP         1         Deny
SSS   YYY         1         Deny
SSS   YYY         1         Deny
SSS   YYY         1         Deny
```

Similarly for 2nd and 3rd ID, my target table should have 10 and 7 rows.

I am trying to assign Units value to variable but it says subquery returned more than 1 value.

```
declare @loopcounter int,@maxunits int
select @loopcounter=1
select @maxunits =(select max(units ) from #unit roup by ID, code)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: When you think about SQL Server, and loop comes to mind... stop and think again. It's *almost* always the worst option. Just a good rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have less than 100, then just go for a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select u.row_ID, u.ID, u.Code, u.units, u.status, 1 as n
      from #unit u
      union all
      select row_ID, ID, Code, units, status, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < u.units
     )
select row_ID, ID, Code, units, status
from cte;
```

A recursive CTE will work on more than 100 units, but you will need to use `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.

Comment: thank you very much.. this was really helpful. i have more than 100 recursions.